# Height of iframe keeps increasing drastically with editor.html in url AEM6.1

Tags: aem

I am using AEM6.1 with sp2. When I open my page with `editor.html` in the page url, the height of the `iframe` keeps increasing drastically. For that reason, my page is not being loaded properly. But when I open this page in classic UI or using cf#, it loads perfectly.  Does anyone have any solution for this, in order to keep the height constant?
Is it because of the AEM version? Because I had some issues with `editor.html` earlier too. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

[Iframe's style Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vSz.png)

Comment: same here in AEM 6.2 with SP1

Answer (score 3):

Same issue in AEM 6.2 SP1. In my case the root-cause was elements specified with `min-height` in `vh` units. The fix was to override them with `%` units when in `wcmmode.edit`.

Comment: I had similar issue where I had `height` in `vh` unit and it was causing issue in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue with AEM 6.2 in Touch UI edit mode, Height of ContentWrapper and iframe was increasing drastically throughout the site.

The reason was, we were using a css class in our base page with the below properties, which :

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -298px;
}
```

here, the bottom margin was given in -ve that's why height of ContentWrapper and iframe was increasing drastically in author mode.

To fix this issue, setting the bottom margin property to positive value solved the problem as in below example:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0px;
}
```

**Note:** The ContentWrapper class is only added in Touch UI edit mode that's why the issue was coming only in this mode not in classic and preview mode.